# Posicionar elementos de manera correcta Android

Tags: android, android-studio

**Buenas, tengo este diseño que como verán a la hora de cargar los datos, quedan desalineados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código del diseño, es el siguiente:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TableLayout
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp">
                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/Cabecera"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:text="Zona"
                        android:id="@+id/tvZona"
                        android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                        android:textSize="26sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:text="Mín"
                        android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                        android:textSize="26sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Máx"
                        android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                        android:textSize="26sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:text="Promedio"
                        android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                        android:textSize="26sp" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/RecyclerListaPrecios"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Y el código del diseño del RecyclerView, es el siguiente:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    style="@style/CardView.Light">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blanco">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TableLayout
                android:stretchColumns="4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="25dp">
                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/Cabecera"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvCiudad"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Ciudad"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/negro"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvMin"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:text="Mín"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/negro"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvMax"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:text="Máx"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/negro"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvProm"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:padding="5px"
                        android:text="Promedio"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/negro"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Alguien me podría decir cómo hacer para que se mantenga la estructura del diseño y no se desalineen los datos que se cargan. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En los `TextView` que se encuentran dentro de `TableRow` define :

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

para que los texto se justifiquen hacia la derecha.

Comment: ¿Con ello conseguiría que se alineen de manera correcta?

Comment: si, deseas alinearlos a la derecha de cada columna verdad?

Comment: No, lo que deseo es que estén centrados en base a la posición de Zona/Min/Max/Promedio